# Modifing XSD for to use substitutionGroup

Tags: xml, xsd

I need help changing the xsd file by using substitutionGroup or Choice, Below is the   xsd file I used  in my code, Now I started receiving the XML data with tag "Organization"  instead of "INDIVIDUAL", except that change , all other tags were same. How I can I accommodate the change in my xsd file . 
I tried  changing the xsd like Below ,but my xml is not getting validated against the schema.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Substitution group works with elements declared as global elements (they are not defined within a type but a top level of a schema).

In case your Individual element and Organization element are globally defined:

```
<xs:element name="INDIVIDUAL">
    <!-- ind. element content -->
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="ORGANIZATION" substitutionGroup="INDIVIDUAL">
    <!-- org. element content -->
</xs:element>
```

Then you only need to use a reference to the head of the substitutionGroup to be valid:

```
<xs:element name="TEST">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="INDIVIDUAL">
```

Individual or any element substituable to individual will be valid here.
So you mainly need to make your element global before using substitution.